# What is the alternative for using host network in docker run command on a Windows host?

Tags: docker, networking, windows-container, windows-networking

As per the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/),

> The host networking driver only works on Linux hosts, and is not supported on Docker Desktop for Mac, Docker Desktop for Windows, or Docker EE for Windows Server.

we cannot specify network="host" while running the `docker run` command on a Windows host. So, what is the alternative for that so that the container would be able to utilize the Windows host networking stack?

Comment: IME it's pretty unusual to need host networking at all.  What problem are you trying to solve that you think you need it?  If publishing individual ports out of a container isn't enough, is running the program outside a container a reasonable option?

Comment: @DavidMaze Something like - the container getting the IP address from DHCP instead of from the local IP pool.

Comment: Usually the container-private IP address is an implementation detail; you can't interact with it at all in most environments, and you never need to look it up or set it.

Comment: Actually, a container getting an IP address from the DHCP server is very common in production environments. On Windows, you need an overlay network. I blogged about it here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/docker-host-network-alternatives-for-windows-containers/ba-p/3390115

The final answer on which network is best for you depends on the environment. If this is a single node for testing, go with Transparent. If production on-premises go with Overlay. If you're using Swarm or Kubernetes, I'd recommend checking their networking options.